# Extracting text from plain HTML and write to new file

Tags: html, python-3.x, pycharm, xbrl

I'm extracting a certain **part of a HTML** document (to be fair: basis for this is an iXBRL document which means I do have a lot of **written formatting code** inside) and write my output, the original file **without** the extracted part, to a .txt file. My aim is to measure the **difference in document size** (how much KB of the original document refers to the extracted part). As far as I know there shouldn't be any difference in HTML to text format, so my difference should be reliable although I am comparing two different document formats. My code so far is:

```
import glob
import os
import contextlib
import re


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout2file(fname):
    import sys
    f = open(fname, 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    yield
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    f.close()


def extractor():
    os.chdir(r"F:\Test")
    with stdout2file("FileShortened.txt"):
        for file in glob.iglob('*.html', recursive=True):
            with open(file) as f:
                contents = f.read()
                extract = re.compile(r'(This is the beginning of).*?Until the End', re.I | re.S)
                cut = extract.sub('', contents)
                print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")
                print(cut, end="\n")
extractor()
```

**Note:** I am NOT using BS4 or lxml because I am not only interested in HTML text but actually in ALL lines between my start and end-RegEx incl. all formatting code lines.

1. My code is working without problems, however as I have a lot of files my FileShortened.txt document is quickly going to be massive in size. My problem is not with the file or the extraction, but with **redirecting my output** to **various txt-file**. For now, I am getting everything into one file, what I would need is some kind of a "**for each file searched, create new txt-file with the same name as the original document**" condition (arcpy module?!)?

Somehting like:

File1.html --> File1Short.txt

File2.html --> File2Short.txt
...

2. Is there an easy way (without changing my code too much) to invert my code in the sense of printing the "RegEx Match" to a new .txt file instead of "everything *except* my RegEx match"?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a sample of a file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: For the moment not as I am on another computer. Later on I will. However my problem is not with the file or the extraction, but with redirecting my output to various txt-file. For now, I am getting everything into one file, what I would need is some kind of a "for each file searched, create new txt-file with the same name as the original document" condition (arcpy module?!).

Comment: Ah ok. that is straight forward

Comment: Edited my answer for better understanding

Comment: So http://pastebin.com/MD0EM63G? I just used open and write as I find it a lot more readable, I also forgot to remove the with stdout2...

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. Error: path is not defined. Do I need any special module?

Comment: sorry, `from os import path`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/6930p/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/CutFile.py", line 42, in <module>
    extractor()
  File "C:/Users/6930p/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/CutFile.py", line 24, in extractor
    with open(file) as f, open("{}Short.txt".format(new)) as out:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Prod224_0001_00057548_20130331 - KopieShort.txt'.
Name of the first html file would be "Prod224_0001_00057548_20130331 - Kopie"

Comment: Do I still need with stdout2file("FileShortened.txt"):? This writes only to one file, however I would need for each searched file one .txt file?

Comment: `Prod224_0001_00057548_20130331 - Kopie.html` is the current name?

Comment: Yes, but this is just a test version. Normally it would be simple Prod224_0001_00057548_20130331.html (without the - Kopie)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EYkUvr0p, that should make `Prod224_0001_00057548_20130331.html`, `"Prod224_0001_00057548_20130331Short.txt"`, pass the full path whatever dir you want the new files stored in

Comment: I used the code exactly as you posted and the process is finsihed after execution but I neither get a .txt file in my directory nor any other output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Any idea how I can skip those files that doesn't match my RegEx (using the code in the answer). I tried it with if regexp.search(content) is not None: out.close() but this didn't work....

Comment: yes you can check the subn value, also close is not needed, the context manager will do that for you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
Final Code is:

```
import glob
import os
import re
from os import path


def extractor():
    os.chdir(r"F:\Test")  # the directory containing my html
    for file in glob.glob("*.html"):  # iterates over all files in the directory ending in .html
        with open(file) as f, open((file.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + ".txt", "w") as out:
            contents = f.read()
            extract = re.compile(r'Start.*?End', re.I | re.S)
            cut = extract.sub('', contents)
            out.write(cut)
            out.close()
extractor()
```